# Can anyone please explain TFLite quantization part found in Netron neural network viewer?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I was checking tflite file in Netron. There I found the quantization formula in Netron as below:

```
quantization: 0.007709330413490534 * (q + 3)
```

I know the quantization formula is: quantized_value = (r/S + Z) Where, r = input, S = scale and Z = zero-point

I have used quantization-aware training before converting the model to the TFLite model. I have uploaded the [TFlite Model file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cBwUvIo532nLLS64a7d-Hr_a5yY9iL55/view?usp=sharing) to [Netron App website](https://netron.app/) where I have found quantization as below image. Can anyone explain What do the q and 3 mean in Netron quantization?

[image]

Comment: Hello. Can you 1. put your **specific** question in the title, and 2. provide the link to the source where you took that screenshot from?

Comment: I have added the file and edited the title.

Comment: Thanks. You may also want to [format the equations with latex/mathjax to improve the readability](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer to this doubt I had. Here, 0.007709330413490534 = 1 / S, q = input, Z = 3. Basically, this is the formula to quantize the input value. If you pull out 1/S then it becomes clear. Here, is an [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/inside-quantization-aware-training-4f91c8837ead) related to this topic.

Comment: are you sure about 0.007709330413490534 = 1 / S ? It means S = 1 / 0.007709330413490534 ? I don't understand it

Answer (score 1):

The quantization formula is `real_value = scale * (int_value - zero_point)`.

- Scale is calculated as `(float_max - float_min) / (int_max - int_min)`.
- Zero point is calculated as `int_min - (float_min / scale)`.

- `float_max` is the max value in the float number line.
- `float_min` is the min value in the float number line.
- `int_min` is the min value in the integer number line.
- `int_max` is the max value in the integer number line.

`quantization: 0.007709330413490534 * (q + 3)` means integer value `q` is mapped to float value using the scale `0.007709330413490534` and zero point `-3`.

The zero point is the offset that shifts the integer value and scale is the factor that scales this integer value to a float value. Confused? Please check [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/40339/30950) which explains the intuition.

If you have any doubts, please feel free to ask.

Cheers,

Thomas.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).